# Delay Execution on Separate iOS thread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading

In my application I need to process an array of Data and send it to server only if internet connectivity is available. I need to perform this task on separate thread so the normal execution of Application is not interrupted.

I have created a class called `ProcessQueue` that iterates over the array and sends it to server.

I need to perform this task on ApplicationDidBecomeActive event with a delay of some seconds but on a separate thread.

I tried following but selector just doesn't get called. (I am trying to set breakpoints inside `ProcessQueue` class).

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self performSelector:@selector(processTheQueue) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
});


- (void) processTheQueue
{

    QueueProcessor *process = [[QueueProcessor alloc] init];
    [process processQueue];

}
```

I have also tried to use performSelector inside the `[process processQueue]' method instead of`dispatch_async` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
   double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // code to be executed on main thread.If you want to run in another thread, create other queue
        [self repeateThreadForSpecificInterval];
    });
```